# Prizes awarded in statistics, data mining and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, computational-statistics

Are there any prizes awarded for major contributions in statistics, data mining or machine learning like famous [Fields medal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal) in mathematics?

[The only prize](http://stat-computing.org/awards/jmc/winners.html) that I have found so far concerns only computational statistics.

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of awards for contributions in statistics. If you are interested on them, take a look at [Prof. Peter Hall's](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/Personnel/profile.php?PC_id=308) and [Prof. David Cox's](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~cox/cv-drc.html) profiles. They have basically won every award invented in the last century.